# Recycle vector by starting from the end

Tags: r

I'm trying to recycle a vector, but don't want to recycle with the default in R.

Imagine I have 2 vectors with unequal number of elements:

```
gen1 = 2:10
gen2 = 1:10
rbind(gen1,gen2)
```

This gives this table

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
gen1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10     2
gen2    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
```

As you can see in the last column, the 2 gets paired with 10. But I want this:

```
gen1 = c(2,2:10)
gen2 = 1:10
rbind(gen1,gen2)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
gen1    2    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
gen2    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
```

Now the 2 is duplicated, but at the front. Evidently I do not want to do this by hand since I have a collection of these non pairing vectors which I want to use this trick. Is there a way to do this?

Or perhaps a way to find the 'closest' position possible in the list.

For example, if I have

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
gen1    8    9   10    8    9   10
gen2    5    6    7    8    9   10
```

I would like this to be:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
gen1    8    8    9    9   10   10
gen2    5    6    7    8    9   10
```

Answer (score 1):

### First example in question

**1)** Convert each to a ts series with appropriate alignment and then use na.locf.

```
library(zoo)

# inputs
gen1 <- 2:10; gen2 = 1:10

t(na.locf(cbind(gen1 = ts(gen1, start = 2), gen2 = ts(gen2)), fromLast = TRUE))
```

giving:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
gen1    2    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
gen2    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
```

**2)** It can also be written with pipes like this

```
cbind(gen1 = ts(gen1, start = 2), gen2 = ts(gen2)) |>
  na.locf(fromLast = TRUE) |>
  t()
```

**3)** If you want to derive the aligment from the data itself use this:

```
maxlen <- max(length(gen1), length(gen2))
cbind(gen1 = ts(gen1, end = maxlen), gen2 = ts(gen2, end = maxlen)) |>
  na.locf(fromLast = TRUE) |>
  t()
```

**4)** Another approach is to use dynamic time warping.

```
library(dtw)

with(dtw(gen1, gen2), rbind(gen1 = gen1[index1], gen2 = gen2[index2]))
```

giving:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
gen1    2    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
gen2    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
```

### Last example in question

The last example in the question seems entirely different and is just a matter of sorting each row.

```
# input in reproducible form
m <- rbind(gen1 = c(8, 9, 10, 8, 9, 10), gen2 = c(5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10))

t(apply(m, 1, sort))
```

giving

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
gen1    8    8    9    9   10   10
gen2    5    6    7    8    9   10
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the trick:

```
gen1 = c(2,2:10)
gen2 = 1:10
ddd=rbind(gen1,gen2)
ddd[1,] = sort(ddd[1,])

ddd

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
gen1    2    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
gen2    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
```

Comment: As you can see gen1 and gen2 don't have the same length. by combining them, the shortest vector gets recycled. But the small numbers are now paired with large numbers. Sorting them is the answer I was looking for.  It makes the number 'closer' in the sequence (small numbers are on one side, larger numbers on the other).